# Replacing contents of a .txt file with another .txt file (preserving original filename)

Tags: python, text

Problem: I have a series of .txt documents in one directory and I want to replace the text with the text from a single .txt document – but I want to preserve the original document filenames.

I created this code (with a lot of research):

```
import os


data = open("source.txt")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Folder/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
             with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                 text = f.read()
                 print('%s read' % filepath)
             with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
                 f.write(data.read())
                 print('%s updated' % filepath)
```

It works... but only for the first file in the directory. All the other files become empty (ie the original text is deleted but the new text isn't added).

Thanks in advance for you help

Comment: You should `read` only once, see [here](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#methods-of-file-objects)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After calling `data.read()` the whole content of `data` was read. So calling `data.read()` again results in an empty string, as you are still at position `EOF`.

To re-read the content of `data` you need to change the file object's position by using the `seek` method:

```py
import os


data = open("source.txt")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Folder/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
             with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                 text = f.read()
                 print('%s read' % filepath)
             with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
                 f.write(data.read())
                 print('%s updated' % filepath)
                 # Set position back to beginning
                 data.seek(0)
```

A much simpler solution would be to store the content of `data.read()` in a variable, i.e. `content` which you can re-use when writing to the series of .txt documents. In that case you don't need to worry about the file`s position anymore.

```py
# Read source.txt only once
with open("source.txt") as data:
    content = data.read()

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('Folder/'):
    for file in files:
        if file.endswith(".txt"):
             filepath = os.path.join(root, file)
             with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
                 text = f.read()
                 print('%s read' % filepath)
             with open(filepath, 'w') as f:
                 # Write content of variable content to file
                 f.write(content)
                 print('%s updated' % filepath)
```

With this you only read the content of your `source.txt` once and you can access it anytime by using your `content` variable.

Comment: Thank you @Wolric!

I'm pretty new to all of this, so I appreciate your help.

If I was to use your simpler solution, how would I write that?